# Persisting query string in angularjs ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a newbie to Angular. Currently I've a challenge I'm been working for hours. I thought of posting here. The problem is how can I preserve the query string value when the route changes in Angular. I'm using the ui router. The querystring has an uid that will be send in each request which I could able achieve through httpinterceptor. But I really got struck up in preserving the uid in querystring whenever the route changes. Can anyone give some insights on this please?

Answer (score 1):

When using ui router you (usually) specify the url, template and controller for that state:

```
.state('mystate', {
    url: "/mystate",
    template: "<p>Some template content using scope: {{title}}</p>",
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.title = "State 1";
    }
});
```

To preserve the query string between states you can add a state param to your states:

```
.state('mystate', {
    url: "/mystate?myParam",
    ...
    ...
},
```

You can then access the parameter in the state controller with `$stateParams.myParam`.

**Note:** You have to pass `myParam` when changing state:

```
$state.go("mystate", {myParam: "yourValueGoesHere"});
```

[Read more in ui router doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Comment: I believe it has to be `url: "/mystate/:myParam",` rather than `url: "/mystate?myParam",`

Comment: You can actually use either one: `url: "/mystate/:myParam"` for URL parameters and `url: "/mystate?myParam"` for query parameters.

Comment: Yes but using ? is not conventional as I understand...maybe I'm wrong though

Comment: I agree that using `/user/:id` is preferable to `/user?id`. However, sometimes you might want to pass several / other params that are not so obvious or compliant with the RESTful architecture. Eg. `/cars/toyota?limit=25`

Comment: you could do it this way: `url: "/carState/:carMake/:limit"`

Comment: Yes you could, but then `limit` isn´t optional. Transitioning to `/cars/toyota` would not be a valid state.

Comment: make it optional then:) `/:limit?`

Comment: :P My bad :-) However I don't think it is very RESTful to set `limit` as a URL param like that as it doesn't refer to a specific resource. But that's another discussion :)

Comment: I would go for oData in this case and use `filter` parameter